# Can not change Statusbar backcolor

Tags: .net, winforms, powershell, statusbar, backcolor

This is my powershell code to create and change backcolor of a statusbar control:

```bsh
#region Statusbar
$status = New-Object StatusBar
$status.SizingGrip = $false
$status.BackColor = [Color]::AliceBlue
#endregion
#region Add to Form
$form.Controls.Add($textbox)
#$form.Controls.Add($menu)
$form.Controls.Add($status)
#endregion
```

But the statusbar color is same, with any value for backcolor. Actually the backcolor doesn't change when I set that... How can I change the backcolor?

Comment: Have you tried StatusStrip instead of StatusBar? A ToolStrip can actually set a BackColor.

Comment: @Jimi I tried that now and that worked! thanks!